# C extract some data from my string with sscanf or else

Tags: c

I am very poor in C, I just learning it. I have a string like:

```
 a          322  4.1   5.2
```

(with whitespaces/tabs/spaces)

or

```
 b     1.22  4.1   5.2 4.11
```

what is the way to get all the strings without whitespace 
so:

```
string[0]="s";
string[1]="322";
string[2]="4.1";
```

etc...

**edit**

I just trying to find the best/fastest way to do it, for big line numbers. (70-100.000 strings)

Working on Android/galaxy s/linkedlist

test: 71.000 arrays took about 7-8 seconds with C++(without string/std), 14 sec with java

Comment: Anything to do with JNI?

Comment: this is a jstring, jstring s = (jstring) env->GetObjectArrayElement(stringArray, i);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the original poster asked using `sscanf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    // 5 elements, each of 32 bytes, 31 for characters the 32nd for storing \0
    char string[5][32];
    char* inputString="a          322  4.1   5.2";
    memset(string,0,sizeof(string));//to initialize to NULL, always be safe on C
    sscanf(inputString,"%s%s%s%s",string[0],string[1],string[2],string[3]);
    printf("res0= %s\n",string[0]);
    printf("res1= %s\n",string[1]);
    printf("res2= %s\n",string[2]);
    printf("res2= %s\n",string[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

This will print:

```
res0= a
res1= 322
res2= 4.1
res2= 5.2
```

Comment: @lacas What do you mean by that?

Comment: i d like to use it as a parser, so absically my String is a 3 MB file, it is splitted by enter (jarray)

Comment: How slow?, a test program on my box with reading a 3.5MiB file uses less than 300 ms of CPU time with a array of size 969454 and 64 bytes wide. you can try strtok(), but is not re-entrant and mangles the original string. Next thing is to code your parser in assembler.

Comment: whats box? i testing it in a mobil phone. (galaxy s) 71.000 strings took about 7-8 seconds, but my java parser took about 14 seconds, this is a 3.1 MB .obj file. I work with linkedlists

Comment: There is NO way that a bytecode interpreted program can run faster than native C code. You made a big mistake on your C development/compilation. I  don't know if you compiled with debugging symbols+debugger attached or the fault lies at your parsing code. I can't help you with the peculiarities of the Android NDK. You should seek compilation/performance help on the toolkit, not the language. Try the C and "java" code on a normal PC and see for yourself the performance difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strtok`, as Martin Beckett said, which is recommended for portability. However, if your system has `strsep` available, I'd go with it. Its man page on BSD has the solution to your question in the examples section.

```
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char input[] = " a          322  4.1   5.2"; 
    char **ap, *argv[5], *inputstring = input;

    for (ap = argv; (*ap = strsep(&inputstring, " \t")) != NULL;)
        if (**ap != '\0')
            if (++ap >= &argv[10])
                break;

    /* degubber output for `p argv':
     *
     * $1 = {
     *  0x1001009a1 "a",
     *  0x1001009ac "322",
     *  0x1001009b1 "4.1",
     *  0x1001009b7 "5.2",
     *  0x0
     * }
     */
}
```

Comment: what is the faster on a lot of strings?

Comment: @lacas Hmm, good question. strsep has a much smaller implementation over strtok, which is marked as "obsolete" in the manual. So I see no real reason not to use it. If you need to make your program run in systems without strsep, go ahead and [implement it](http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-763.12/string/strsep-fbsd.c). And if performance is really important, you could implement your own way of parsing the string.

Comment: hello! I am trying to implement a c++ parser to android. So the speed is very important.

Answer (score 0):

Safest way to split a string (especially if you don't know what the string may contain) is [strtok](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Finding-Tokens-in-a-String.html).

You might also need to check how you are creating the string[] array in 'C'

Comment: hello, i need the fastest method, is it?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0,j=0; str[i]; i++)
{
    if(str[i]==' ')
        continue;
    str2[j]=str[i];
    j++;
}
```

In the above code, `str` is your previous string and `str1` is the new.